Tailwind - How do I wrap flex cards that have a class of relative without them losing shape?
How do I place flex cards created in Tailwind that have the following class side by side in columns of 3 and rows of 4 without their original shape changing?
class="relative isolate flex flex-col justify-end overflow-hidden rounded-2xl px-8 pb-8 pt-40 max-w-sm mx-auto mt-24"

I am able to position them side by side by putting them into a parent container with a class of "flex flex-wrap" as posts on this and other sites recommend but when I do so they change from being horizontally long to vertically long.
This is their original shape before wrapping it in a div with a class of flex as most posts I've seen suggest to get them side by side.
original shape of card
And this is what the shape of the card changes to after wrapping it in a div with a class of flex.
shape of card in div with a class of flex

For debugging questions please edit your question to include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it. See How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
